# Where can I submit a change to the build of Ubuntu ISO's?

Tags: grub2, system-installation, uefi, 64-bit

Using 20.04 with grub-ia32-efi-bin (manually unpacked grub) I was able to add files to the install ISO to get it to boot from USB media on an old Intel Baytrail tablet.

Baytrail has always been a total pain, and used to suffer crashes back in 14.04 and 16.04 days, however 20.04 is really stable, and only needed the install media changed in-order to be able to boot and successfully install.

I'd like to know where I can submit a change to the official Ubuntu ISO build process. This would be to ensure in-future all 64-bit builds include a 32-bit grub, so that 64-bit machines with 32-bit EFI (mostly older machines to my understanding), can still install Ubuntu without needing to manually follow the steps I did.

Comment: That's now how I remember the comments, but sure, if you say so. What do you mean by "that was not core Ubuntu, which merged already"? That was to be merged into `lp:~ubuntu-cdimage/debian-cd/ubuntu`... which sounds pretty "core Ubuntu" to me. Wherever I might be dwelling, I definitely didn't see any evidence of anybody being snarky except for you with these comments about the sky.

Comment: file a feature request https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1341944  It is unlikely Ubuntu is responsible for packaging this though not is Debian where we get it from. Both don't support 32-bit.